# Google AdSense alternative for the Netherlands

Tags: google-adsense, alternative

The AdSense account of a client of mine got banned by Google, after filing a reconsideration requests it ends in a permanent deactivation.
I'm now investigating the alternatives he has when it comes to placing text ads on his Dutch website. Which other companies are out there that offer the same (or more:) capability of Google's in context text based ads for Dutch websites?

Comment: Whats the reason the client got banned? It helps to know for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: Invalid click activity, he got a warning in his gmail but since he doesnt use gmail a lot, he missed that warning.
I asked him if he actually did click his ads and the ban was correct, and apparently friends were trying to help him make money and clicked the ads too much. So the ban by Google was fair, but that doesnt solve his problem now. I already told him he should not expect Google to lift the ban, but rather look for alternatives, since I dont know any good ones...well...here we are :)

Comment: I had the same excat problem, with friends thinking they would help out, by clicking on the ads, and unfortunately it is impossible for one to get google to lift the ban. The wierd thing is that I didn't get any warning at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good method to find the answer is: Use the same network as other top websites in the Netherlands (or many other countries) are using, excluding AdSense of course:

1. Browse the top 100 Dutch websites and take note on those who uses text
   and banner ads
2. Find the companies behind their ad sales
3. Contact those ad placement companies and ask how to join their network

A free place to find out which are the top sites in any country is [Google Ad Planner](https://www.google.com/adplanner/)

If your client has a website with loyal visitors and a common interest, your client can try to sell ad placement directly to anyone that wants to promote something to those visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe binlayer.com has text ads if you don't mind a German company. Their pop-up ads can be a good income source but Google ads is better. I'm not very sure about text ads you need to verify it yourself.